# FieldArray component does not work

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-form

`FieldArray` component does not work.
I use the `redux-form` package.

My code is below:

```
import React from 'react'
import { FieldArray, reduxForm } from 'redux-form'
import { connect }   from 'react-redux'

const renderMembersPP = ({ fields, meta: { touched, error, submitFailed } }) => (
    <ul>
      {fields.map((member, index) =>
          <li style={{width:'5',height:'5',backgroundColor:'red',color:"white"}} key={index}>
            show?
          </li>
      )}
    </ul>
)

let NextWeekDriftForm = (props) => {
  const { handleSubmit, pristine, reset, submitting} = props
  return (
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <div>
          <FieldArray name="members" component={renderMembersPP}/>
        </div>
        {JSON.stringify(props.initialValues.members) }
      </form>
  )
}

NextWeekDriftForm =  reduxForm({
  form: 'NextWeekDriftForm',     // a unique identifier for this form
})(NextWeekDriftForm)

export default NextWeekDriftForm =  connect(
    state => ({
      initialValues: state.sendGood.driftMemberArray.formData,
    })
) (NextWeekDriftForm)
```

`{JSON.stringify(props.initialValues.members) }` render some data.
In other words,`members` is an `array` and it has value.

I set the `fields.map` return  `<li>show?<li/>`, however, I don't see the `show?`.

In my opinion, the result should is:

> show? 
>     show? 
>    `text` of  {JSON.stringify(props.initialValues.members)}

Now the result is :

> `text` of  {JSON.stringify(props.initialValues.members)}

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I add the `enableReinitialize: true,`. Now, it works well.

```
export default NextWeekDriftForm =  connect(
    state => ({
      initialValues: state.sendGood.driftMemberArray.formData,
      enableReinitialize: true,
    })
) (NextWeekDriftForm)
```